# STDEV.P IF cells in the column contain specific text "*cta*"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to perform STDEV.P calculation based on criteria in one column.

My current formula is:

```
{=STDEV.P(IF(Aggregated!Y$15:Y$3000="*cta*",Aggregated!AD15:AD3000,""))}
```

E.g. the case of `AVERAGE(IF...` is much simpler cos I do not use `"="` but instead have `"*cta*"` as one of the criteria.

The result is #DIV/0!

PS. I face a similar issue with `MAX(IF(...` where the criteria is `"*cta*"`

Please advise. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`=STDEV.P(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cta",Aggregated!Y$15:Y$3000)),Aggregated!AD15:AD3000))`

and for `MAX`:

`=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cta",Aggregated!Y$15:Y$3000)),Aggregated!AD15:AD3000))`

Comment: Yup, I have added it before I saw your answer :) I focused too much on his other ("MAX") issue. Thanks